# How to change value of the active cell when clicked using VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I am not sure whether this is running, has errors, or whether the variables are correct. I followed steps online to check what my variables are, like typing ?variable in the immediate window, checking the locals window, and hovering my mouse over the variable, but nothing comes up.

Nothing happens regardless when I go back to the workbook.

Here's a screenshot:
[image]

Included a screenshot because the problem might not be just with the code.

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.address = "C5:I5" Then
        Dim row As Integer
        row = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).Value, Range("$n$1:$n$365"), 0)
        Dim address As Long
        address = Application.WorksheetFunction.address(row, 15)
        Range(address).Value = Range(address).Value + 1
        ActiveCell.Value = Range(address).Value
    End If
End Sub
```

The purpose is to add 1 to the value of the active cell when clicked. The cell's value will change based on the date in the cell directly above it; the value needs to be tied to the date. I plan to accomplish this using a hidden array of ascending dates and values, located at n1:o365.

Comment: Your code will only execute if you're highlighting C5:I5, you need to look at intersect maybe for cells within this range

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**(a)** Probably your intention is to check if the target cell is within the range "C5:I5" - what your checking is if target has the address "C5:I5" so the if fails.
Use for example the function `Intersect` for that

**(b)** (Minor thing) Declare `row` as Long

**(c)** There is no `.WorksheetFunction.address` function. A Range has an Address property, eg `Target.Address`. Note that this will return a String, not a Long. But you don't need this anyhow. Use `Cells` if you know row and column of a cell.

Note that I haven't checked your logic to find the correct row.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    
    If Intersect(Target, Range("C5:I5")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    Dim row As Long
    On Error Resume Next
    row = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(Target.Offset(0, -1).Value, Range("$n$1:$n$365"), 0)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If row = 0 Then Exit Sub    ' Row not found

    Dim cell As Range
    Set cell = Cells(row, 15)
    cell.Value = cell.Value + 1
    Target.Value = cell.Value
End Sub
```

Comment: This is very helpful--thanks! Found out why I couldn't get vba to do anything--macros are blocked by my organization lol. I'll try this on another machine and follow up on whether it works.